# keras tuner does not create checkpoint files

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I used keras tuner in direct approach in time series forecasting on VScode on windows11. I attempted to predict values for 7 days in the future, and created 7 models for each day.

I created a tuner 7 times in a for loop.

```
def slice_direct(i):
    # use input as it is
    # y[:, i] ... : = all parts of a batch.  i = prediction-period (forecast horizon)
    
    return lambda x, y: (x, y[:, i])

i=0

class MyHyperModel(keras_tuner.HyperModel):

    def build(self, hp):
        tuned_window_size = hp.Choice('window_size', [10,20,30])
        activation = 'tanh'
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        # Tune the number of hidden layers.
        second_hidden_layer = hp.Choice('second_hidden_layer?', [0, 1])
        third_hidden_layer = hp.Choice('third_hidden_layer?', [0, 1])

        if second_hidden_layer == 0:
            model.add(GRU(
                    units=hp.Int("units_first_layer", min_value=10, max_value=200, step=10),  # tuning the num of units
                    activation=activation,
                    input_shape=[tuned_window_size, feature_nums],  # use self.window_size here
                    return_sequences=False
                ))
        else:
            model.add(GRU(
                    units=hp.Int("units_first_layer", min_value=10, max_value=200, step=10),  # tuning the num of units
                    activation=activation,
                    input_shape=[tuned_window_size, feature_nums],  # use self.window_size here
                    return_sequences=True
                ))
            
            if third_hidden_layer == 0:
                model.add(GRU(
                        units=hp.Int("units_last_hidden", min_value=10, max_value=200, step=10),  # tuning the num of units
                        activation=activation,
                        return_sequences=False
                        ))
            else:
                model.add(GRU(
                        units=hp.Int("units_last_hidden", min_value=10, max_value=200, step=10),  # tuning the num of units
                        activation=activation,
                        return_sequences=True
                        ))
                model.add(GRU(
                            units=hp.Int("units_last_hidden", min_value=10, max_value=200, step=10),  # tuning the num of units
                            activation=activation,
                            return_sequences=False
                ))
        
       
        model.add(Dense(1))
  
        optimizer_name = hp.Choice('optimizer', ['adam', 'sgd'])
        if optimizer_name == 'adam':
            optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        elif optimizer_name == 'sgd':
            learning_rate = hp.Float("learning_rate", min_value=1e-5, max_value=1e-2, sampling="log")
            optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
  
        
        model.compile(
            optimizer=optimizer,
            loss=hp.Choice('compiled_loss', ["mse",'mae']),
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
        )
        
        return model
    
    def fit(self, hp, model, train_data, val_data, i=i, callbacks=None):
        # convert train_data into train_dataset
        tuned_window_size = hp.get('window_size')
        fd = Form_data(forecast_horizon, tuned_window_size, batch_size)
        train_x, train_y = fd.split_data_into_xy_multi_direct(train_data)
        val_x, val_y = fd.split_data_into_xy_multi_direct(val_data)
        train_dataset = fd.transform_npdataset_tfdataset(train_x, train_y)
        val_dataset = fd.transform_npdataset_tfdataset(val_x, val_y)
        model.fit(train_dataset.map(slice_direct(i)), epochs=50, verbose=0, validation_data=val_dataset.map(slice_direct(i)), callbacks=[early_stopping])
        
        # evaluate the performance for one of the prediction days
        predictions = []
        actuals = []
        for x, y in val_dataset.map(slice_direct(i)):
            prediction = model.predict(x, verbose=0) # (409, 7) slide windows * 409 times
            predictions.append(prediction)
            actuals.append(y.numpy())
        
        # Convert lists to numpy arrays
        predictions = np.concatenate(predictions)
        actuals = np.concatenate(actuals)

        # unscaling
        unscaled_predictions = np.copy(predictions)
        unscaled_actuals = np.copy(actuals)
        for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
            unscaled_predictions[i] = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions[i].reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
            unscaled_actuals[i] = scaler.inverse_transform(actuals[i].reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
        mse = MSE(unscaled_actuals, unscaled_predictions)
       
        return mse



models = {}
hyperparameters = {}
for i in range(forecast_horizon):
    tuner = keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization(
            MyHyperModel(),
            objective=keras_tuner.Objective("fit", direction="min"),
            max_trials=5,
            overwrite=True,
            directory="hp_tuning",
            project_name='direct'
        )
    tuner.search_space_summary()
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
        tuner.search(train_data=scaled_train_data, val_data=scaled_val_data)

    best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=5)[0]
    best_hyperparameters = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

    # 辞書に保存
    models[i] = best_model
    hyperparameters[i] = best_hyperparameters
```

and the error below occured. The folder 'hp_tuner' and 'direct' were created, checkpoint files were not.

NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for hp_direct\untitled_project\trial_2\checkpoint

Comment: Hi @Ten this error message indicates that the TensorFlow TensorSliceReader failed to find any matching files for the checkpoint.
This could be due to various reasons, including incorrect paths, permissions, or issues with the checkpoint saving logic.
Make sure that the directory path where you are trying to save the checkpoints exists and is accessible. Verify that the folder ‘hp_tuning/direct’ exists and that the program has the necessary permissions to read and write to it.